Chernoff bound for sampling flipped bits and arriving at true average
The Basic Setting
Let there be an $n$-bit string generated by $n$ successive trials of random variable $X$,  name the string $x_1,..,x_n$, with $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. Define sample mean as $\bar{X} = \sum_i^n x_i$, and expected value (actual mean) as $p_x = E[X]$.
The goal is to determine the likelihood that the string sample mean generated from $x_1..,x_n$ deviates from the actual mean by more than $\epsilon$, with confidence $\delta$.
This is a standard Chernoff bound problem, using the bound
\begin{equation}
Pr[|\bar{X} - p_x| \geq \epsilon p_x] \leq exp \biggr( -\frac{\epsilon^2}{2+\epsilon} \cdot p n \biggr)
\end{equation}
we need $n$ to be $n \geq \frac{2+\epsilon}{\epsilon^2} ln \frac{2}{\delta}$ to get $\bar{X} \in [p_x - \epsilon, p_x + \epsilon]$ with confidence $\delta$.
The twist
Now let's say we do not observe $x_i$, but instead observe corrupted bits $y_i$ whereby with probability $q$, $y_i = x_i$, and with probability $1-q$, $y_i = \neg x_i$.
Similarly, define $\bar{Y} = \sum_i^m y_i$, and $E[Y] = p_y$. So we have:
\begin{align*}
Pr[y=1] &= Pr[y=1|x=1]pr[x=1] + Pr[y=1|x=0]pr[x=0]\\
&= q \cdot p_x + (1-q) \cdot (1-p_x)\\
\\
Pr[y=0] &= Pr[y=0|x=0]pr[x=0] + Pr[y=0|x=1]pr[x=1]\\
&= q \cdot (1-p_x) + (1-q) \cdot p_x\\
\end{align*}
The question
Now the question is how many $m$ bits of $y_i$ do we have to sample to get $\bar{X} \in [p_x - \epsilon, p_x + \epsilon]$? Surely $m > n$, but what is the expression of $m$?  Or .. is it sufficent to compute $m$ to get the $y$-bits within $\epsilon$ of $p$: $\bar{Y} \in [p_y - \epsilon, p_y + \epsilon]$. And then from there get the underlying mean of $\bar{X}$?
